# Short condition in java

Tags: java

I have 4 `String` variables: a, b, c , d.

I check if one of them is `null` then `return false`.

so i do:

`if(a==null || b ==null || c ==null || d ==null) return false;`

Has any short way for this?

(i'm beginning for java)

Comment: Do you want to return `true` if that's not the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your method looks like this:

```
public boolean foo() {
    String a = "a", b = "b", c = "c", d = "d";
    if(a == null || b == null || c == null || d == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then there is a way you could reduce code. You could do this instead:

```
public boolean foo() {
    String a = "a", b = "b", c = "c", d = "d";
    return (a != null || b != null || c != null || d != null);
}
```

But, if you had more strings to test, say, 10, or even 100, a strategy that would require less code would be to put the strings into an array and use a *for-each* loop. In fact, the following method would work with any type of *object*, not just *strings*.

```
public boolean containsNullObject(Object... objs) {
    // loop through each string
    for(Object o : objs) {
        if(s == null) { return false; } // return false if string is null
    }
    // if there was no instance of a null object, return true
    return true;
}
```

If you don't know what an *array* or *for-each* loop is, look at these:

- [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
- [Foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Comment: yes, this `public boolean containsNullObject(Object... objs)` is what i need. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, your solution is the simplest possible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this could be expressed a bit more elegantly with a foreach loop and a `String` [vararg](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).  It would read nicer and allow you to easily debug your statement.

```
// method only returns true if all strings are non-null
public boolean all(String... strings) {
    for(String str : strings) {
        if(null == str) {
           return false;
        }
     }
     return true;
 }
```

You would then call it in this manner:

```
return all(a, b, c, d); // will return false if any of these are null, otherwise true.
```

Answer (score 0):

**-** You are using `Non-Short circuit OR` to evaluate the condition, which i think is the most apt and simplest in this case.

**-** So your solution is what it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

`if` is redundant here, just use `return !(a == null || b ==  null || c == null || d == null);`